# triggers in mysql getting an error

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm trying to create a trigger that will update some value, and if the row is not exists than insert a new row with value = 1.

I wrote the trigger in 3 possible ways and all of them are getting error

version 1:

```
CREATE TRIGGER stat_trg BEFORE INSERT ON comments
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO statistics 
      SET item_id = NEW.item_id,
          likes = 0,
          comment = 1
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
      SET comment = OLD.comment + 1;
  END;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'SET comment = OLD.comment + 1' at line 9

version 2:

```
CREATE TRIGGER stat_trg AFTER INSERT ON comments
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE num integer DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT comment into num FROM statistics
      WHERE item_id = OLD.item_id;
    SET num := num + 1; 

    INSERT INTO statistics (item_id, comment, likes) VALUES (num,1,0)
END;
```

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 4

version 3:

```
CREATE TRIGGER stat_trg BEFORE INSERT ON comments
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO statistics (item_id, likes, COMMENT) VALUES (NEW.item_id,0,1)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  
      comment = comment + 1;
  END;
```

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds > to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 6

All looks good according to examples that I found, what am I missing?
Please help on this issue. 
Thanks.

Comment: Please check [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). You're trying to inject arbitrary procedure code inside a SQL statement.

Comment: tried it as well, same error.

Comment: could you share table design of `statistics ` ?

Comment: I changed comment column to --> comments (made no difference, just sound better). anyway...
item_id  Index mediumint(9)
likes                 int(11)
comments int(11)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `stat_trg` BEFORE INSERT ON `comments`
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO `statistics` set item_id= NEW.item_id, likes = '0', comments = '1' ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
      comments = values(comments) + 1;
  END$$
  DELIMITER ;
```